# A tale of two comments

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, comment-flags, welcoming

Not too long ago there was a question where someone had found code elsewhere and wanted it modified. At the core of the code was a `(Get-Date).AddDays(-1)` (which is PowerShell for "subtract one day from the current date and time"). The question boiled down to "this subtracts one day, so how do I subtract 5 minutes" showing no attempt to solve the problem (and yes, the solution would've been `(Get-Date).AddMinutes(-5)` as most of you probably guessed right away).

The question received its share of downvotes, but hadn't been closed yet. When I re-visited it some time later someone (an experienced user no less) had posted an answer, so I left a comment on the answer asking them to avoid encouraging people who were obviously refusing to use their brain. That comment was deleted within mere seconds (well, maybe that's an exaggeration, but it can't have been more than 5 minutes), presumably for being unwelcoming.

Now imagine my surprise when today I come across this little gem that has been sitting there for at least half a day and *still* hasn't been deleted an hour after I flagged it for abuse.

> [image]

"GFY", for those unfamiliar with the term, is short for "go f*** yourself". I don't know about anyone else, but where I come from that is most definitely considered rude (to say the least).

I can understand how my comment was deleted for being unwelcoming, because it definitely was¹. What I cannot understand is how comments that are clearly far more offensive are not removed with the same vigor.

**Addendum:**

Since some people seem intent on derailing this into a discussion about what a hostile prick I am: I'm not complaining that my comment got deleted. At all. My complaint is about how much longer it took to get a comment deleted that is *actually offensive*.

---

¹ And FTR: I fully intend to continue being unwelcoming to people who clearly did not waste even a single thought on solving their problem themselves.

Comment: Has your comment flag been handled or is it still pending? If pending: It's Sunday. Even moderators have weekends.

Comment: I don't think "GFY" is in the current word list that makes the comment flag eligible for single-flag deletion. Anyway I've just deleted that comment.

Comment: _"I fully intend to continue being unwelcoming"_, technically wouldn't that be grounds for closing your account as that would mean you don't accept the terms of use for Stack Overflow?

Comment: I also just checked the "brain" comment you made - it wasn't single-flag instant deleted as well. Actually I was around at that moment and handled the flag.

Comment: GFY can also mean "Good For You", depending on the context. (Just like SGTM can either mean "Silently Giggling To Myself" or "Seems Good To Me"). FWIW, acronyms kinda are confusing (totally IMO)... Thanks Twitter.

Comment: What the heck does FTR mean?  Is the F the f-word?

Comment: @HansPassant For the Record? Or maybe F**k the Rules? Like Bhargav said above acronyms are ambiguous ...

Comment: Should somewhere be a recommendation for users to avoid acronyms where possible? In this case I would definitely say it's more "Good For You" instead "Go F*** Yourself" (ok, maybe too naive ;)). There could also only be a hint in the flagging dialog or whatever.

Comment: But if acronyms can mean several things then everyone can choose their own meaning and we can cater to everyone at once. We should have *more* FA.

Comment: I don’t know why this question is closed as “unclear what you’re asking”. It’s perfectly clear what you’re asking. Also, I don’t know why it’s being downvoted. There was an imbalance of treatment here, favoring a unmotivated new user over an established user who has proven his mettle. And for those arguing “GFY” *could* have been intended to mean “good for you*... does that phrase make sense in context? How about the other one? Let’s not BS ourselves, please (note: BS here is not a naughty term, it refers to the Black-Scholes algorithm.)

Comment: Well, what surprises me most from this question is learning that some people interpret "GFY" as "go F yourself". I've always seen it unambiguously as "good for you". As a consequence, I would have found the _abusive_ flag exaggerated (although the comment is indeed superfluous).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Let me put it this way: I don't agree that "being welcoming" should include people who are just looking for a sucker to do their work for them. If that is what StackOverflow is aiming for, then the site is bound to share the fate of other help-vampire-infested sites: knowledgeable people (the ones who are providing the majority of answers) will get fed up with the flood of crappy questions and leave. Which in turn will lead to an overall decrease of quality. SO is working so well *because* we do have standards.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Being unwelcoming means that you are actively engaging users in a negative manner. Have you considered just ignoring them, downvoting and voting to close where necessary. In my experience that reduces your stress levels and doesn't get you into discussions. The fact we don't want to be welcoming to help-vampires, doesn't mean we need to engage them with hostility.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: "*I don't agree that "being welcoming" should include people who are just looking for a sucker to do their work for them.*" Then perhaps you should recognize the difference between "not being welcoming" and "being unwelcoming". You don't have to welcome such people with open arms. You don't have to communicate with them at all. But calling them "obviously refusing to use their brain" isn't appropriate.

Comment: @NicolBolas I am well aware of the difference. And I wasn't communicating with the person who asked the question, but another person who posted an answer to that question.

Comment: @BhargavRao *"Yes I understand the code.Thought I might be able to get some help on it. Guess I was wrong. Good for you."* Does that make sense to you? Yes, many acronyms are ambiguous by themselves. However, that ambiguity usually vanishes when they are put in context.

Answer (score 8):

> What I cannot understand is how comments that are clearly far more offensive are not removed with the same vigor.

There are plenty of ways:

1. A matter of who is flagging. When you posted your hostile comment on the answer, the answerer was automatically pinged. Thus notifying the person *most likely* to flag it. By contrast, the OP's comment did not `@` you; this means that only the answerer would be pinged. And since the OP's comment directed its hostility at the person who was being hostile towards the answerer, it's hardly unreasonable for the answerer to think of that hostility was being directed at a target *deserving* of it. So the answerer is less likely to flag a comment defending their post.

   That's not our policy; we don't want hostility *period*. So the answerer is clearly not doing their job right. But then again, considering your standpoint:

   > I fully intend to continue being unwelcoming to people who clearly did not waste even a single thought on solving their problem themselves.

   Clearly, you're no stranger to respecting our policies *only* when it personally suits you. So why are you so shocked that other people might also respect our policies only when it suits them?

   In any case, the flagging of the OP's comment would most likely be up to whomever happens to wander by. Which brings us to:
2. Not as many people saw it. Answering a question bumps it on the main page. As such, it will attract more attention. And the first comments on such an answer will therefore be seen by more people than *replies* to those comments. If the answerer isn't going to flag it, and nobody else sees the comment, then it goes unflagged.
3. If a passer-by happened to see both your and the OP's comment, then they might feel that the OP's hostility towards you was not the problem. That he was merely responding in kind towards your hostility. So they would be less inclined to flag the OP's comment. Again, you have no moral high ground to judge such behavior on.
4. Misunderstanding of what "GFY" was intended to mean. It's clear in context what the user was trying to say. But if not many people are going to see it anyway (due to #1), it only takes one or two people to make a mistake in understanding it and allow the comment pass without flagging.

   This misunderstanding is compounded by the fact that, without your comment being replied to, the context was lost. The OP's comment seemed to be attacking a phantom. So passers-by might just shrug and move on.

So yes, there are plenty of ways this can happen.

Comment: Just to be clear, my comment on the answer was by no means hostile towards the person who posted the answer. It was a polite request to stop a behavior the I consider counter-productive.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: I can't see the comment, so I can't know for certain. But statements like "obviously refusing to use their brain" and "I fully intend to continue being unwelcoming" make me skeptical that I will agree that your post was "by no means hostile."