# Create tag [amps]

Tags: support, status-declined, tags

I tried to ask a question and creating the [amps] tag with that question. That is referring to https://developer.atlassian.com/server/framework/atlassian-sdk/working-with-maven/, namely the Atlassian Maven Plugin Suite, short AMPS.

But creation of the tag fails with:

> You are attempting to create the tag [amps]; however the tag [amp] already exists! If you think this new tag should be allowed, raise it on meta

What now?

Comment: Such is the problem with acronyms.  Consider the existing [atlassian-plugin-sdk] tag, do tell us why it was hard to find or inappropriate.

Comment: @HansPassant okay, then the proper one would probably be `atlassian-maven-plugin-suite`, I find the `atlassian-plugin-sdk` a bit too general, the amps is a specific sub-set of working with the SDK.

Comment: Creating little islands where nobody can find each other anymore and nobody can leverage their existing knowledge and learn something new is not useful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let us not. Acronyms are usually [ambiguous](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375042/a-tale-of-two-comments#comment636240_375042), and do not make good tags. The better tag name as Hans as already mentioned, would be to spell it out completely.

The very [amp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amp) which you mention is already in a (small) mess. It is being used to tag questions related to:

- Asynchronus Messaging Protocol (AMP)
- Alfresco Module Package (AMP)
- Access Module Processor (AMP)
- Advanced Message Processor (AMP)

If we add another tag AMPS, it probably would start receiving questions regarding these four topics.

Comment: But "Amps", "ohms" and "volts"... are not acronyms :)

Comment: RIP tags on [electronics.se] ... we should create some new electronics device that has AMPS as an acronym just to trolll them. :p