# Wrong usage of the [tsx] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

111 Open Qs are tagged [tsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tsx), whose Usage guide is:

> Intel's Transactional Synchronization Extension for optimized memory access in multi-threaded code

However, most are about React (a JavaScript library). See the combinations with:

- [reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs), 62
- [jsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsx), 31
- [react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-native), 4
- [typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript), 72
- other 14 (including [jestjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jestjs), [mithril.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mithril.js), [typescript2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript2.0))

There are only four questions with both [tsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tsx) and [intel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intel) (though also others tagged [tsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tsx) with [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) etc.).

How can this be resolved?

Comment: So there's around 100 questions tagged with this at all...The two questions I have are, how pertinent are those Intel questions compared with TypeScript, and would it make sense to prefix the Intel-specific tag with `intel-`?

Comment: @Makoto it's not only TypeScript but also React. I thing the last option is the best one.

Comment: jsx seems to suffer from the same fate. Top questions are about react and the adobe scripting language

Comment: The [first usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tsx?sort=newest&page=3&pagesize=50) should determine what the tag is for (first come, first claim), if it needs to be renamed to something less ambiguous or it has been piled-on is another matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Acronyms are usually [ambiguous](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/380172/4099593), and do not make good tags. In this case there seems to be 3 uses, one for the Typescript tsx, one for the React tsx, and one for the actual Intel TSX. First things first, let's clear out the obvious:

- Create a new tag for the Intel tsx, [transactional-synchronization-extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transactional-synchronization-extension). If that is too large, we can use Makoto's suggestion of [intel-tsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intel-tsx).

After searching a bit, it looks like [typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript)  [tsx is a file extension for](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html)  [jsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsx), which already is present. However that tag itself seems to be in a larger mess than [tsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tsx). There have been many requests trying to create better tags for [jsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsx):

- [Proposal: rename [jsx] to [altjs-jsx]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315831/proposal-rename-jsx-to-altjs-jsx)
- [Should the jsx tag stop being a synonym to reactjs?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370595/should-the-jsx-tag-stop-being-a-synonym-to-reactjs)
- *"There are also some questions about extendscript (the Adobe javascript ) that are also tagged [jsx], since that's the file extension. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/extendscript+jsx https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsx+adobe"*  - [From a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315831/proposal-rename-jsx-to-altjs-jsx#comment662547_315831).
- [Should we burninate [jsx]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349578/should-we-burninate-jsx) (Which has been downvoted and roombad).

Therefore it probably isn't a good idea to use the [jsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsx) tag for retagging TypeScript [tsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tsx) questions, as it is better to not add more fuel to fire.

One way to solve this tangle is to tackle it in phases.

- First we create a new tag:

  - retag all the TypeScript related [tsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tsx) questions to [typescript-tsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript-tsx).
  - retag all the ReactJS related [tsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tsx) questions also to [typescript-tsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript-tsx). This is because the documentation makes it clear that TSX is a file extension of TypeScript files.
- Then we add [tsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tsx) as a synonym of this new tag, in order to prevent its recreation and subsequent misuse.
- Finally we ask for the disambiguation of [jsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsx).

Comment: I'm not agree with the `react-tsx` tag because TypeScript tsx will always being combined with React _(see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html)_. Just keep `tsx` and create `intel-tsx` is enough.

Comment: @H.Pauwelyn, Cool. If that is the case, we need to merge [react-tsx] with [jsx] as well. But before we move forward, we need to get some confirmation from a user who is well versed with Typescript and react. Perhaps find one in the JS room?

Comment: @BhargavRao `jsx` looks like a tag that is not related to react. The tag wiki points to  `react-jsx`

Comment: @jontro, aha, thanks for that. We're now getting into the territory where we _have_ to talk to the TypeScript and React guys. I will rope them in later this evening, if they haven't yet found this by then..

Comment: @H.Pauwelyn In the link you provided, it states: "JSX rose to popularity with the React framework, but has since seen other implementations as well". So, while `tsx` is *predominately* used by React, it's not *only* used by React. That said.. I don't see a reason to have a [tag:react-tsx] tag either, unless React has it's own implementation.

Answer (score 3):

@AlexGuteniev and I have retagged the Intel TSX x86 transactional memory questions from
[tsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tsx) to [intel-tsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intel-tsx).

I made a modified copy of the tsx tag wiki for [intel-tsx](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/intel-tsx/info), and edited the [tsx tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tsx/info) to a placeholder that explains the situation.  JavaScript people can write a proper tag wiki if they want, or they can continue ignoring everything in their wiki.

Comment: I'm also thinking it makes no sense to use [tag:rtm] for Intel TSX; probably need to retag relevant [tag:rtm] questions to [tag:intel-tsx] as well.

Comment: @AlexGuteniev: yes, rtm should probably be a synonym for intel-tsx.  TSX includes RTM and HLE, otherwise we could have used that instead of creating intel-tsx.  No need to delete the RTM tag from existing questions, though.  I think it's harmless.  I don't yet have the 5 score in the tag necessary to nominate a synonym.  That probably has to wait for a database update; I do have [2 answers with 6 total upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bintel-tsx%5D+user%3A224132).

Comment: I'm not sure how synonym will work without re-tagging, as, again, most of [tag:rtm] questions are not about Intel TSX

Comment: @AlexGuteniev Oh FFS, ok yeah, will edit then.

Comment: @AlexGuteniev: AFAIK I got everything.  Still waiting for one RTM question to have your edit approved; unfortunately I picked "approve" a while ago and can't upgrade that to approve + edit, annoying SO misfeature.

Answer (score 1):

[status-done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-done)

In case [intel-tsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intel-tsx) has not enough questions, found a few more by search for `intel tsx -[intel-tsx] -[tsx]`:

- [Disable Hardware Lock Elision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19822943/disable-hardware-lock-elision)
- [Will runtimes like CLR and JVM be able to use Haswell TSX instructions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13757997/will-runtimes-like-clr-and-jvm-be-able-to-use-haswell-tsx-instructions/14320269)
- [Emulating Intel TSX instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14055367/emulating-intel-tsx-instructions)
- [Try out Intel TSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30377628/try-out-intel-tsx)
- [Intel TSX hardware transactional memory what do non-transactional threads see?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22593146/intel-tsx-hardware-transactional-memory-what-do-non-transactional-threads-see)
- [Haswell Transactional Memory read-set and write-set information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069432/haswell-transactional-memory-read-set-and-write-set-information)
- [mysterious rtm abort using haswell tsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069492/mysterious-rtm-abort-using-haswell-tsx)
- [Assembly x86 REP, REPZ, REPNZ, XACQUIRE and XRELEASE instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46487511/assembly-x86-rep-repz-repnz-xacquire-and-xrelease-instructions/46488080)

UPD: I also wanted to acquire those into the new tag, but I cannot make the decision if some of existing five tags should be sacrificed for that

- [Hardware Transactional Memory in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43939732/hardware-transactional-memory-in-java)
- [Thread Signaling Within Transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19804137/thread-signaling-within-transaction)
- [How to use XACQUIRE, XRELEASE Hardware Lock Elision (HLE) prefix hints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51578062/how-to-use-xacquire-xrelease-hardware-lock-elision-hle-prefix-hints)